# setting an array element with a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'd like to create a numpy array with 3 columns (not really), the last of which will be a list of variable lengths (really).

```
N = 2
A = numpy.empty((N, 3)) 
for i in range(N):
    a = random.uniform(0, 1/2)
    b = random.uniform(1/2, 1)
    c = []
    A[i,] = [a, b, c]
```

Over the course of execution I will then append or remove items from the lists. I used numpy.empty to initialize the array since this is supposed to give an object type, even so I'm getting the 'setting an array with a sequence error'. I know I am, that's what I want to do.

Previous questions on this topic seem to be about avoiding the error; I need to circumvent the error. The real array has 1M+ rows, otherwise I'd consider a dictionary. Ideas?

Comment: "I used numpy.empty to initialize the array since this is supposed to give an object type" - what? No. If you want an array of object dtype, tell it you want that with `dtype=object`.

Comment: Default dtype for `np.empty` is float.  Examine a trial `A`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for correcting my misconception. A = numpy.empty((N, 3)).astype(object)  works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `A` with

```
A = numpy.empty((N, 3), dtype=object)
```

per [numpy.empty docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html). This is more logical than `A = numpy.empty((N, 3)).astype(object)` which first creates an array of floats (default data type) and only then casts it to object type.